# Erro em ListActivity, provavelmente relacionado a OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview

Eu estou com um problema para entender o que está dando de errado neste código, sinto que o problema pode estar relacionado ao OnItemClickListener. Quando tento emular ele responde com uma mensagem assim: "Unfortunately, MyAplication has stopped.".

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<ViewListing> arrayList;
private ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<ViewListing>();
        arrayList.add(new ViewListing(0, R.drawable.anjelly, "Item 1"));
        arrayList.add(new ViewListing(1, R.drawable.construct, "Item 2"));
        arrayList.add(new ViewListing(2, R.drawable.darkdestroyer, "Item 3"));

        ListViewAdapter adp = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);

    setListAdapter(adp);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(position) {
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo pelo menos 3 problemas no código:

1 - A `ListView list` está a ser inicializada fora do método `onCreate()`.

2 - É necessário chamar o método `setContentView()`, caso o seu *layout* não seja apenas uma *ListView*.

3 - Para poder usar o método `setAdapter()` da ListActivity, o **id** da *listView* tem de ser `@android:id/list`.

O método `findViewById()` procura a *view* dentro do *layout* passado ao método `setContentView()`, tem por isso ser usado depois.

Altere esta parte do código assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<ViewListing> arrayList;
    private ListView list;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//Altere se o nome do layout for outro.

        list = getListView();//O id da listView tem de ser @android:id/list.

        ......
        //restante do código
}
```

Para mais informações ver [ListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) na documentação.